# can not use some urls to cconvert videos in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to perform some functionality using ffmpeg. It is working if url is ending with `.mp4` but if it is not working with urls not ending with `.mp4`.
one of the example is below -

```
ffmpeg -i https://player.vimeo.com/external/202414841.sd.mp4?s=4f9ef25c7c52a64a5788afb5181a51d0f31f2f43&profile_id=164 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 0 -b:a 128k -c:a libopus output.webm
```

error I am getting:

```
[1] 12115
-vf: command not found
```

this is working fine-

```
ffmpeg -i http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 0 -b:a 128k -c:a libopus output.webm
```

I can make it work by downloading the video and renaming it but it will take a lot of time. Is there any other way?

Comment: Show the full log from the not working command.

Comment: You have to quote url

Comment: @llogan I have added it on the post. but what  Баяр Гончикжапов mentioned worked for me . Thanks guys I really appreciate it.

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов It worked. Thank you, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов Want to make that the answer? Or I can close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @llogan No, thanks, close it

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the argument into quotes as mentioned before. But wanted to add an explanation. So when your argument `&profile_id=164` contains ampersand which has a special meaning:

https://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html

So because your URL had ampersand the single command got broken up into a partial command with partial arguments. So that's why the error. You will encounter this problem with different applications as well, for example wget, curl etc...

Either quote the URL or use a simpler version of the URL. Often I didn't need that big URL with all the arguments, but for scripts which have to accept any URL it's just safe to put it into the quotes no matter if it's not always needed.